# Mapped drive letters immediately available?

Tags: powershell-2.0, mapped-drive

I am using this to map a drive letter in PowerShell v2, and it works in that the drive letter shows up and is usable in Explorer.

```
$Network = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Network"
$Network.MapNetworkDrive($drive.name, $drive.value, $true)
```

However, if I then try to use that drive letter to do anything in Powershell, say to create a folder, I get a DriveNotFoundException. But as I said, the drive is there and usable manually. I thought I might need to wait for a bit, or refresh Explorer, or both, but doing so seems not to affect anything. However, if I turn around and rerun the script, which checks in advance to see if the drive is there, and only creates it if not, it will see the drive and not recreate, and a following task will work fine. As if perhaps the drive letter is session based?
I also tried adding

```
New-PSDrive -name:($drive.name -replace ':', '') -psProvider:FileSystem -root:$drive.value -scope:Global
```

as well, in the hopes that this would provide a session based drive, but no good.

An additional wrinkle is that the script has to be Run as Administrator, but again, if I do it as two different scripts, one to create the drive and one to use it, it works when both are Run As Administrator. It's only when both tasks are done in the one script that it fails.

One last point, I know PS 3 has a better way to handle mapped drives, but due to things beyond my control I am limited to PS v2.

Comment: There can be a space or a colon, either works, and I find the colon connects the parameter and value visually, which makes the code more readable for me.
EDIT: Did the comment asking about the colons get deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible in PowerShell v2. To have `New-PSDrive` create a Windows drive you need to add the parameter `-Persist`, which isn't available in PowerShell v2.

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849829.aspx):

> `-Persist`
>
> Creates a Windows mapped network drive. Mapped network drives are saved in Windows on the local computer. They are persistent, not session-specific, and can be viewed and managed in File Explorer and other tools.

I'd say your best option (aside from upgrading to PowerShell v3 or newer) is to use the [`net`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_subcmds.mspx?mfr=true) command:

```
& net use $drive.name $drive.value /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Hmm, so an old DOS command might not have the issues of the VB Script approach? Will have to try that tomorrow!

Comment: The command comes from Windows NT and has nothing to do with DOS.

Comment: Ah, yeah, not good to conflate "Command line" with DOS. Different critters. That said, I tried the Net Use approach with the same results. I get the drive letter in Explorer, but if later in the code I try to create a folder using the drive letter it errors with DriveNotFoundException. :( BUT, when I made a little two line test it worked, so perhaps the fact that in use I have multiple functions. More to test.